How can I make my custom icon for the snipping tool appear in the task bar in Windows 11 Home?
Here is my odd problem - I created a custom icon for the snipping tool.
I can pin it to my Start menu just fine, but if I pin it to the taskbar, the icon is invisible.
I only see the words snipping tool if I roll over it, and it does Function if clicked, just invisible icon.
Oddly enough, this issue does not occur in Windows 11 Pro, or in Windows 10, only in Windows 11 Home. Does anyone know how I can make the custom icon visible in the taskbar?
I should also note I have custom icons for all my apps in the taskbar, and the only one with this invisibility cloak is snipping tool.
